# APPLY and Passing Arguments to Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Note: This is in SQL Server 2008.

I'm trying to use the APPLY operator to allow me to call user-defined in-line table-valued functions on each other in a sensible manner, but it doesn't seem to faithfully do so.  I'm using OUTER APPLY, but CROSS APPLY does the same thing.  Here's the relevant chunk:

```
SELECT addresses.Book,addresses.Page,foo.BookInput,foo.PageInput
FROM [dbo].bookPageFromAddress(@address) addresses
outer apply [dbo].[imageFileFromBookPage](addresses.Book, addresses.Page) foo
```

Nothing is bizarre:

```
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].imageFileFromBookPage (@book nvarchar(max), @page nvarchar(max))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN(
    WITH ids AS (
        SELECT right('00000000'+ltrim(str(c.DocID)),8) as VarString,
               right('0000000000'+ltrim(str(i.ImageID)),12) as PathVar6        
        FROM [Resolution].[dbo].[Constant] c, [Resolution].[dbo].[Images] i
        WHERE ltrim(c.[Book]) like @book 
        AND ltrim(c.[Page]) like @page
        AND i.DocID = c.DocID
)
SELECT '/Images/' +
    substring(ids.VarString,1,2)+'/' +
    substring(ids.VarString,3,2)+'/' +
    substring(ids.VarString,5,2)+'/' +
    right(ids.VarString,8)+'/' +
    PathVar6 + '.tif' as ImageLocation
    ,@book as BookInput, @page as PageInput
FROM ids
```

);

So, in essence,imageFileFromBookPage outputs its input to BookInput and PageInput.  Here's the result of that outer apply on sample input:

```
Book 4043
Page 125
BookInput NULL
PageInput NULL
```

Note that Book and Page are strings, not integers; they just happen to be holding numeric characters here, but BookInput and PageInput are really NULL, not strings.  I thought at first it was a typing issue; both Book and Page are nchar(10) in their original table, and both of my functions expect nvarchar(max) inputs.  I tried CASTing the arguments as nvarchar(max) and got identical results, however.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?  I'm not familiar with APPLY, but it sure seems like what I want, here.  How do I get APPLY or something like it to actually pass along values to the next function?

EDIT:  Modified code above to include more information.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking

Comment: @Andomar: According to his function def, BookInput should be 4043 instead of NULL and PageInput should be 125 instead of NULL.

Comment: TToni is correct, Andomar.  My core question is "How do I get APPLY or something like it to actually pass along values to the next function?" (I am referring to user-defined in-line table-valued functions).  I am curious about APPLY, but I'll accept any solution to my problem.  If my post was confusing I'm happy to edit it but I'm not sure how to be clearer.

Comment: @TToni: Aha.  quindraco, could you post the entire user-defined function?  Especially how you use the `return` statement.

Comment: This works fine in the little test I just wrote (also with nchar(10) vs nvarchar(max)). So your problem is probably in the "irrelevant" bits :-). Usual debugging techniques here are either to start with a simple code that does what you want and then work towards your actual code until something breaks or to go the other way round from your existing code.

Comment: Ok, sure, sorry about that.  I posted the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the APPLY docs, shouldn;t the function be declared as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].imageFileFromBookPage (@book nvarchar(max), @page nvarchar(max))
     returns @Data Table
     (
          book nvartchar(max),
          page nvarchar(max)
     )
as
begin
   insert into @Data
   select @book, @page;

end
```

In other words, it's not a problem with APPLY, it's a problem that your function needs to return a Table.

Cheers -

Comment: Since it seemed unclear, I've edited my original question to not skip the "irrelevant bits" and instead show the declaration you're talking about.

Comment: I did wonder about that :( Does it make a difference that you're not defining the columns in the return as part of the pre-amble before the AS?